# ELK Index Lifecycle Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am using ELK for Kong API Gateway logs. I am getting the below index error after applying ILM policy manually by adding the following lines in the index settings:

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.refresh_interval": "1s",
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.lifecycle.name": "kong-index-policy",
  "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "kong",
  "index.lifecycle.indexing_complete": "true",
  "index.routing.allocation.include._tier_preference": "data_content",
  "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "20000",
  "index.priority": "100",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "1"
}
```

**Error:**

`index lifecycle error illegal_state_exception: index [kong-2022-11-17-000001] has [index.lifecycle.indexing_complete] set to [true], but is still the write index for alias [kong]`

I tried to use Retry policy execution API `POST kong-2022-11-17-000001/_ilm/retry` but the issue is still exist.

How to solve this issue please?

Comment: Why did you add `index.lifecycle.indexing_complete: true` manually? The only reason to do it is when you want to [skip rollover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/skipping-rollover.html)

Comment: If I set `"index.lifecycle.indexing_complete": "false"` in the index settings, that will solve the issue, please?

Comment: Once you set it to true, you cannot roll over your index anymore. So set it to false and try again

Comment: @Linux_Admin it should indeed work, if so. Please write it in the answer section :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved when setting `"index.lifecycle.indexing_complete": "false"` in the index settings